# Widening exception of overridden method in Java

Tags: java, exception

Assume we have two classes:

Class A:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class A  {
    public void test() throws IOException{
        System.out.println("test in A");
    }
}
```

Class B:

```
  import java.io.IOException;

  public class B extends A {
      @Override
      public void test() throws Exception{
          System.out.println("test in B");
      }
 }
```

This gives a compiler error, and I would like to know the reason for it. I can get the answer by myself, but this is not fully scientific, but partly logically.

I wrote [a blog post in Azerbaijani](http://javacigenclik.blogspot.com/2015/04/niy-override-olunan-method-un-exception.html). When I wrote the blog I was stuck in the loading process.

Please be careful in quotes:

> I think that when the compiler reads the B class, it loads the method headers of A and method headers of B. And when you call test of A, the JVM calls the test of A, but as body calls test of B, and at that time we will have this method:

```
 public void test() throws IOException{ // <-- Header of A
    System.out.println("test in B"); // <-- Body of B
    // Here I can throw wide Exception from IOException
    // because here is the body of the test in B. The test
    // method in B can throw Exception so the compiler
    // doesn't approve of this version of the code.
 }
```

Is the process really going on as what I wrote above?

Loading headers issue I was stuck exactly here.
How does the linking process work? I can't figure out background of

```
A a = new B(); // When the compiler converts this line into bytecode
//                does it loads of method headers of A and method
//                body's of B
a.test()
```

calls the test of the B class. I know logically, but I can't figure out at the compiler level, linking process.

Answer (score 9):

Imaigine you have the following code:

```
A a = new B();
try { 
  a.test();
} catch (IOExceoption e) { 
   //do some specific handle for IOExceoption
}
```

Now imaigine what happens if `b.test()` throw an `Exception` which is NOT `IOException`? nobody will handle it, and that breaks java's [checked exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_handling#Checked_exceptions) mechanism.

---

The other way around however, is perfectly fine:

```
public class A  {
     public void test() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test in A");
    }
}
  public   class B extends A {
      @Override
      public  void test() throws IOException{
          System.out.println("test in B");
      } 
 }

A a = new B();
try { 
  a.test();
} catch (Exception e) { 
   //handle
}
```

Now, note that the catch handles a general `Exception`, including the specific `IOException`, and the code will compile perfectly.

Comment: @Serkhan When it sees B.test() overrides A.test(), it checks the matching of the return type and exception as well. They both can be only narrowed and not widen, in order to prevent the situation I discussed in my answer.

Comment: can you explain me linking process.i can't figure out background of

A a = new B(); a.test() calls test of B class.i know logically.but can't figure out as compiler level as linking process.A a = new B(); //when compiler converts this line into bytecode //does it loads of method headers of A and method body's of B or loads of all method headers and method body's.i am asking this to understand how test method of A linking with test method of B

Comment: @Serkhan The error will be generated without any code that instantiate `B`, once the compiler "see"  the declaration of `B.test()` is inconsistent with `A.test()` - the compilation error will be then.

Comment: @Serkhan I you are asking about how the [dynamic dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) is happening behind the scenes it is beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: i am reading wiki article.i think i am searching this term.i couldn't explain my question.Answers are useful and according to most part of my question.Your comment filled my wanted answer.Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The overidden method can throw anything *which is an IOException* your case. Or more generally, it can throw any exception that is a *ParentException*. So, you can throw `FileNotFoundException` since it is also an `IOException`.

> Why?

Not adhereing to this rule breaks the primary contract between parent-child in inheritance.

Somewhere else in your code you can safely assume that the exception thrown from the call to `test()` will *always be IOException* irrespective of *Which implementation of A threw it*. If you were allowed to throw `InterruptedException` in your case, what exception should the caller catch?

The compiler doesn't load anything. It just marks the method as invoke virtual which means this method is overriden and supposed to be called at run-time based on the object type

Comment: @Serkhan - The Compiler realizes that class `A` is the parent of `B`. Thus it also finds out that `test()` is overidden. So,  as a *rule* it checks if the exception thrown by `B.test()` is a `ParentException` or `ParentExceptionChild` which is valid. Else, it is invalid according to the language semantics

Comment: A a = new B(); //when compiler converts this line into bytecode
    //does it loads of method headers of A and method body's of B or loads of all method headers and method body's.i am asking this to understand how test method of A linking with test method of B

Comment: @Serkhan -The compiler doesn' load anything. It just marks the method as `invoke virtual` which means this method is overriden and supposed to be called at run-time based on the object type

Answer (score 2):

From a bit different angle, you are basically not overriding existing method in super type.

Exceptions which are thrown are part of the method's signature.
When you declare your test method in class B with override annotation, you are in fact trying to override (or implement) method which does not exist in its parent A.